# XML problem in the basic menu example

Tags: xml, android, menu

I am trying to create an app with some menus, an I am following the basic example available in the official android site:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

My problems appear when I define the menu in the XML. After creating the folder res/menu and creating the menu_option.xml file from eclipse.... The project (in general) gives an error that can be read from the Problems tab:

```
 
Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output
Android Packaging Problem
```

So, changing to the Console tab to get more information about the problem, this can be read:

```
 
[2010-06-02 11:35:54 - TestAudio] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
[2010-06-02 11:35:54 - TestAudio] W/ResourceType(11566): Bad XML block: header size 63327 or total size -144759824 is larger than data size 0
[2010-06-02 11:35:54 - TestAudio] /home/User/workspace/TestAudio/res/menu/options_menu.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: no element found
```

The strange thing is that eclipse recognizes the menu items that I've defined in the XML,I can reference them in the code with no problems and my main activity builds. (and the rest of the files too).

Could it be that when eclipse creates a file, for some reason, the Android SDK has problems to read it, or something similar??

The XML code is exactly the same as the one in the example, so I don't really know what is happening. The code in options_menu.xml is this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:title="New Game" />
    <item android:id="@+id/quit"
          android:title="Quit" />
</menu>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the source of the XML file in question: TestAudio/res/menu/options_menu.xml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Judging by the position of the error, and assuming you simply copy/pasted the XML from the example, you may be missing the XML declaration which should be on the first line of each XML file for it to be considered [well-formed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Well-formedness_and_error-handling):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Alternatively, you could try a [clean build](http://update.multiverse.net/wiki/index.php/Developing_With_Eclipse#Rebuild) of the project to see if the error goes away

Comment: Hi Chris!

Thanks for your answer!! And you were right! I found the solution before I read your comment. The only thing that I had to do was a clean build and after that, it worked! So...if somebody has this problem...please go to Project/Clean and that's all

Btw, you were right and I didn't add the XML declaration either. I didn't know about that. Thanks for the suggestion too!

Comment: Clean build, now that was a new one. Solved, was getting squeamish already after gazing at idiotic, generic "XML Parse Errors" in the console. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Just add the header tag in the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```